# Cannot start Jupyterlab from the terminal after installation of Jupyterlab with pip3 and python3 with homebrew

Tags: python-3.x, pip, homebrew, jupyter-lab

I want to start Jupyterlab from the terminal

I'm on MacOS 10.14.
I installed Python with Homebrew
I tried to install Jupyter lab with `brew install jupyterlab` but it gave me the following error message:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "jupyterlab" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I the tried installed it with `pip3` with the command `pip3 install jupyterlab`. It worked. But when I tried to launch it with the command `jupyter lab`, I got the following error message:
Error executing Jupyter command 'lab':

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I run the command `brew list`, `jupyterlab` is not in the list

I'm suspecting that the problem lies in the fact that `pip3` and `homebrew` don't manage the PATH the same way and that the problem lies there. What should I do

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just reinstalled jupyter with `brew` (`brew reinstall jupyter`) , re-installed jupyterlab with `pip3 install jupyter lab` and it worked!